# How to make Apache 2.4 redirect sub.example.com to a local server on the orgin?

Tags: apache-2.4

I've been trying to make a sub.example.com go to a local server at http://10.0.2.15:8080 to access my code-server https://github.com/cdr/code-server and cant seem to find the right config. This config I have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
    # Servers to proxy the connection, or;
    # List of application servers:
    # Usage:
    # ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # Example:
    ProxyPass / http://10.0.2.15:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.2.15:8080/
    ServerName images.darksmp.com
</VirtualHost>
```

should have the server name and has the proxy connections. The website does display the login screen for code-server but when logged in, the content isn't loading either.

Is there a way someone can set up a CentOS 8 Server with GUI with http server on it and test it out for them self? That Would be great!

Comment: What is listening on 10.0.2.15:8080 ?

Comment: Gerard H.,
Please go to https://github.com/cdr/code-server as this is what is running on 8080

Comment: I read https://github.com/cdr/code-server/blob/main/docs/guide.md. Don't you need to provide websockets?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use redirect in vhosts config, which works fine in most cases

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
ServerName images.darksmp.com
ServerAlias www.images.darksmp.com
Redirect 301 / http://10.0.2.15:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Just make sure you have routing working well within your network, and that your DNS is resolving also local names if you have defined them.

Comment: This could work bit its has to like CName to the ip instead as the redirect might not work I'll try this method real quick.

Comment: If CName is needed, then best to setup DNS on your local server to point to this internal comp, and should all work flawlessly.  Another option is to make a simple port forwarding like `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -s outside/net -d server-ip --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.0.2.15:8080`, but this is not using apache then.

Comment: But what if i want to use the same port on the machiene and have a html site and a code server on the same ip? this is why im asking.

Comment: Then you need <virtualhost> or define your forwarding site on different port (ie 81) and then forward.  I'm not sure how individual pages (or login pages) would be forwarded via apache.  To have it working flawlessly, I presume the best option is really via port forward, as NAT server would translate every call